# How to avoid NaN value when adding to nodes

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to avoid NaN value when either of the node is null

```
<xsl:value-of select=
"otxsl:var-put('SUM_OF_171_175', Parent[Child=171]/Sibling) + Parent[Child=175]/Sibling)"/>
```

Currently for below structure it gives me an NaN return value because value for 175 Sibling is null. I want it to simplify in one line code wherein null will be treated as zero just to avoid NaN value if possible. Thanks in advance.

```
<GrandParent>
<Parent>
 <Child>172</Child>
 <Sibling>15</Sibling>
 <Child1>172</Child1>
 <Sibling1>172_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
<Parent>
 <Child>171</Child>
 <Sibling>2</Sibling>
 <Child1>171</Child1>
 <Sibling1>171_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
<Parent>
 <Child>175</Child>
 <Child1>173</Child1>
 <Sibling1>173_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently for below structure it gives me an NaN return value because
>   value for 175 Sibling is null. I want it to simplify in one line code
>   wherein null will be treated as zero just to avoid NaN value if
>   possible.

**Use**:

```
sum(Parent[Child[.=171 or .=175]]/Sibling[. = number(.)])
```

This produces the sum of the `Sibling` children whose string value can be cast to a number and that are children of the `Parent` elements that are children of the context node and have a `Child` element with value 171 or 175.

**Here is a short XSLT transformation that evaluates this expression and outputs the result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Parent[Child[.=171 or .=175]]/Sibling[. = number(.)])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to become well-formed):

```
<GrandParent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>172</Child>
        <Sibling>15</Sibling>
        <Child1>172</Child1>
        <Sibling1>172_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>171</Child>
        <Sibling>2</Sibling>
        <Child1>171</Child1>
        <Sibling1>171_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>175</Child>
        <Child1>173</Child1>
        <Sibling1>173_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

**The wanted, correct, non - NaN result is produced:**

`2`